# show - hide component with hook function works only one time

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, tsx

I am trying to show and hide a functional component, it's works only works on load. after hide it's not shows again. i understand that, the way i use the `functional component` in wrong way.

any one suggest me the correct way please?

here is my code : (index.tsx)

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

const App = () => {
  const [isBoolean, setBoolean] = useState(false);

  const showComponent = () => {
    setBoolean(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Hello isBoolean={isBoolean} />
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <button onClick={showComponent}>Show hello component</button>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Hello component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default ({ isBoolean }: { isBoolean: boolean }) => {
  const [isShow, setIsShow] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsShow(isBoolean);
  }, [isBoolean, setIsShow]);

  const shufler = () => {
    setIsShow(false);
  };

  if (!isShow) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>hi {JSON.stringify(isShow)}</p>
      <button onClick={shufler}>Hide Component</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-nij6mm?file=Hello.tsx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to maintain a derived state from prop in child component(**Hello**), you can pass callback and state as props from parent component(**index**) to child.

**Cause of the Problem:**

After hiding the component `isShow` was set to false , `isBoolean` is still true. So the next time when we click the show button `isBoolean` hasn't changed, it's still true which will not trigger the **useEffect** in the **Hello.tsx** , `isShow` was never set to true which causes the child to return null.

**index.tsx**

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

const App = () => {
  const [isBoolean, setBoolean] = useState(false);

  const showComponent = () => {
    setBoolean(true);
  };

  const hideComponent = () => {
    setBoolean(false);
  }



  return (
    <div>
      <Hello isBoolean={isBoolean} hideComponent={hideComponent} />
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <button onClick={showComponent}>Show hello component</button>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Hello.tsx**

```
 import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default ({ isBoolean, hideComponent }: { isBoolean: boolean }) => {
  if (!isBoolean) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>hi {JSON.stringify(isBoolean)}</p>
      <button onClick={hideComponent}>Hide Component</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

To explain why your code isn't working:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setIsShow(isBoolean);
}, [isBoolean, setIsShow]);
```

- initially when you set `isBoolean` to true in parent, this `useEffect` in child runs too
- Then you set `isShow` to false from the child component
- Then again you set `isBoolean` to true in the parent component, but for the `useEffect` above, the `isBoolean` is true now, and it was true also in previous render, so it doesn't run anymore.

So if possible, no need to duplicate `isBoolean` state also in child, just pass it as props and use it directly, as in the other answer.

Comment: Research minds are always welcome first!!

Answer (score 0):

you can simply hide child component

`<div className="hidden"></div>` in tailwind or `display: none;` in css

```
<div className={!isShow ? "hidden" : ""}>
  <p>hi {JSON.stringify(isShow)}</p>             //tailwindcss
  <button onClick={shufler}>Hide Component</button>
</div>
```